# Java Regex Metacharacters returning extra space while spliting

Tags: java, regex, java-8, metacharacters

I want to split string using regex instead of StringTokenizer. I am using String.split(regex);
Regex contains meta characters and when i am using \[ it is returning extra space in returning array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner i= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s= i.nextLine();
        String[] st=s.split("[!\\[,?\\._'@\\+\\]\\s\\\\]+");
        System.out.println(st.length);
        for(String z:st)
            System.out.println(z);
        }
}
```

When i enter input `[a\m]` 
It returns array length as 3 and

```
 a m
```

Space is also there before a.
Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how can i correct it. I don't want extra space in resulting array.

Comment: Do you mean to have an input string `String s="[a\\m]"`?

Comment: Because you match `[` and `]`: http://regexr.com/3ckg2

Comment: I typed just [a\m] at cmd and want a and m as Output

Comment: You're just getting an empty string as first element in array because your input starts with `[` and splitting is done on `[` as well.

Comment: @Snorlax How can i correct it ? Any idea?

Comment: Remove all these characters from the start. http://ideone.com/PXWLYg

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow Thanks. Great Code but i have query in your code. If it is replacing all these then how it is splitting the string?

Comment: No, it does not remove *all*, only those at the start. You are not interested in those leading symbols since they produce empty array elements, right?  So, removing them at the start of string only is a valid approach.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want. Can you explain little bit about it's working if you got 1 or 2 minutes free? 
replaceAll("^[!\\[,?._'@+\\]\\s\\\\]+", "")
like ^ negates then how it is replacing? I am new to this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `[` is at the beginning of the string, when `split` removes `[`, there appear two elements after the first split step: the empty string that is at the beginning of the string, and the rest of the string. [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) does not return *trailing* empty elements only (as it is executed with `limit=0` by default).

Remove the characters you split against from the start (using a `.replaceAll("^[!\\[,?._'@+\\]\\s\\\\]+"`, note the `^` at the beginning of the pattern). Here is a sample code you can leverage:

```
String[] st="[a\\m]".replaceAll("^[!\\[,?._'@+\\]\\s\\\\]+", "")
                 .split("[!\\[,?._'@+\\]\\s\\\\]+");
System.out.println(st.length);
for(String z:st) {
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/PXWLYg)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed Explanation and Code :)

Comment: Sir, if i input only ! or [ it is still returning 1 whereas it should return 0 :(

Comment: It is because when you split an empty string, you will get 1 empty element. Use [this code](http://ideone.com/4iHNHK) to handle that situation.

Comment: Since Java 6, you can use `string.isEmpty()` instead of `string.length() != 0`, but that’s only a stylistic difference…

Comment: I did it using "\\\\" instead of "" while replacing Now it returns 0

Comment: String[] st=s.replaceAll("^[!\\[,?._'@+\\] \\\\]+","\\\\").split("[!\\[,?\\._'@\\+\\]\\s\\\\]+");

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [Wiktor Stribiżew’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907727/2711488), you may do the same without having to specify the pattern twice, by dealing with the [`java.util.regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package directly. Removing this redundancy may avoid potential errors and may also be more efficient as the pattern doesn’t need to be parsed twice:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[!\\[,?\\._'@\\+\\]\\s\\\\]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.lookingAt()) s=m.replaceFirst("");
String[] st = p.split(s);
for(String z:st)
    System.out.println(z);
```

To be able to use the same pattern, i.e. without having to use the anchor `^` for removing a leading separator, we first check via `lookingAt()` whether the pattern really matches at the beginning of the text before removing the first occurrence. Then, we proceed with the `split` operation, but reusing the already prepared `Pattern`.

---

Regarding your issue mentioned in a comment, the `split` operation will always return at least one element, the input string, when there is no match, even when the string is empty. If you wish to have an empty array then, the only solution is to replace the result explicitly:

```
if(st.length==1 && s.equals[0]) st=new String[0];
```

or, if you only want to treat an empty string specially, you may check this beforehand:

```
if(s.isEmpty()) st=new String[0];
else {
  // the code as shown above
}
```